# Cannot add or delete files from opt/ros/hydro/share

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add some files to the location /opt/ros/hydro/share. But I am being denied permission. I have installed ROS as a debian package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174737/cannot-add-or-delete-files-from-opt/ros/hydro/share./) by [Abhishek Jha](https://answers.ros.org/users/18975/abhishek-jha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not put any files in that location. If you are developing your own nodes, create a ros workspace where you have permission to write (see  http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). If you for some reason still want to add files to /opt/ros just use sudo cp.

---

Originally posted by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) with karma: 328 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-24**:
Let me phrase it more strictly: If one tries to add files to /opt and does not understand why it says: Permission denied, one should under no circumstance `sudo cp` files in there as that will very likely lead to ugly problems.